# T-SQL - Do more conditions help the query proceed faster?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets consider a simple table with 2 relevant columns:

```
bit IsDownloaded not null
datetime DateDownloaded null
```

I know that IsDownloaded is 1 only when DateDownloaded has a value (This is just an example I understand that IsDownloaded is not neccessary then).

Is there some performance difference between:

```
SELECT * 
FROM files 
WHERE IsDownloaded = 1 
  AND DateDownloaded IS NOT NULL 
  AND DateDownloaded > '2010-01-01'
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM files 
WHERE DateDownloaded IS NOT NULL 
  AND DateDownloaded > '2010-01-01'
```

Therefore does it help to:

1. Add "easier to evaluate" conditions (such as conditions on boolean datetypes)
2. Add mode conditions in general

Consider that there are no indexes applied on any columns.

Comment: Did you take a look at execution plans ?

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it. But anyway is there some general answer to that or does it differ from query to query?

Comment: No the simple answer would be No, more conditions in where clause mean each row returned has to go through more checks before sql server can return it to you, Now coming to indexes, if you do have more checks and sql server has some indexes to get help from while checking against your where clauses, it can get some help from them indexes to speed up the process. But on the other hand if you has less where clauses sql server would have to do less checks and might wont even need any indexes .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Its all about the indexes, and the selectivity of the query. In the case above, ensuring that there is an index on `DateDownloaded` will drive the performance of the query - the `IS NOT NULL` and `IsDownloaded` checks won't help (if the flag is correlated to the date).

**Explanation**
With no indexes at all, there would be no alternative for Sql other than to iterate through all rows in the table evaluating your where predicate (full scan).

With an index on `DateDownloaded`, the option now exists to use the index to exclude rows from evaluation against the remainder of the predicate (provided that not all `files` have `DateDownloaded > '2010-01-01'`)

(Indexing the `IsDownloaded` flag would probably not be a good idea if this only has 2 states, and if neither state represents less than a couple of % of the data).

So yes, in the general case, you should always use any additional information available, which would further reduce the number of rows to be evaluated (although in truth this is usually an automatic process, since the query would otherwise return the wrong results).

But in the case here, given that as you say the `IsDownloaded` flag is only set if there is also a `DateDownloaded` date, it would be redundant to include this in the predicate (as is the `NOT NULL`) as it will not exclude any additional rows than the > `2010-01-01` criterion.

Answer (score 2):

If the predicates are correlated (as in your case) there will be no performance benefic including them both, rather the opposite. The optimizer makes assumptions and calculations based on statistical information to estimate the cardinality, which is great. Unfortunatelly, when predicates are correlated, optimizer doesn't know that, and makes the same assumptions as they weren't, so possibly generating a wrong execution plan for the query.

Here's link to Paul White's article on the subject:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates